Issue with Loading External Pages in Chromium Browser Tests (Network Error)
I am writing a browser test in the Chromium repository where I try to open external pages, but they fail to load, showing a network error. However, when I set a proxy on my system and change the network settings to manual, specifying the proxy port, the external pages load successfully. I need to load external web pages like google.com, youtube.com, etc., but I am facing this issue only while running the test cases, not when using the browser executable, where I can load web pages normally
I am trying to create a new tab and load an external web page in my Chromium browser test, but I encounter a network error, and the page fails to load. This issue occurs only when running the test case, not when manually using the browser, where the external pages load normally.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
